# "Unable to create shortcut for" on starting Java7 on OSX

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

Whenever I start a JNLP WebStart Application with Java7 on OS X 10.8 I get the following message dialog:

> Unable to create shortcut for XXXX

The console outputs the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/XXXX/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/cache/6.0/37/6bb90625-129dd80a.icns (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
at com.sun.javaws.MacOSXShortcutUtil.copy(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.MacOSXShortcutUtil.createBundle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.MacOSXLocalInstallHandler.createBundle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.MacOSXLocalInstallHandler.createShortcuts(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LocalInstallHandler.installShortcuts(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LocalInstallHandler.performIntegration(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LocalInstallHandler.install(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.notifyLocalInstallHandler(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Cleaning cache, removing deployment cache does not help.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut-bug on OSX existed in Java `7u9`.
It was fixed in `7u10`. You probably need to update your JRE.

**[Discussion](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10647039)**

Comment: That seems to be a different bug. The "unable to create shortcut" message also appears in the 7u10 early access, but the app will launch anyway after confirming the dialog.

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue in Java 8, so its not just a problem in 7.